# Mac M1 Big Sur takes a long time to wake up from sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, big-sur, spotlight, apple-silicon

One of the highlights of the M1 Mac is supposed to be instant wakeup.  However, I find that after several sleep sessions, it starts taking about 30-60s to wake up from sleep.  Unfortunately the console logs are filled with hundreds of

```
Jul  7 08:31:26 mac-mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.0E000000-0500-0000-0000-000000000000[49744]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[7938]
Jul  7 08:31:26 mac-mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.10000000-0400-0000-0000-000000000000[49750]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[7938]
Jul  7 08:31:58 mac-mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.05000000-0300-0000-0000-000000000000[49751]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[7938]
Jul  7 08:33:26 mac-mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.08000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000[49771]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[7938]
Jul  7 08:33:26 mac-mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.0C000000-0600-0000-0000-000000000000[49766]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[7938]
Jul  7 08:33:26 mac-mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.0A000000-0600-0000-0000-000000000000[49769]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[7938]
```

making it very hard to see if there is something obvious (I think these spotlight errors are a different issue).  Any thoughts on how to go about debugging this?

Comment: I'd get the Spotlight issue fixed: it may be a factor. And, as you say, it's masking any other problems. Is your setup unusual in any way? Is the disk full? What Mac model is it?

Comment: Pretty new M1 mini, nothing unusual.  Seems the spotlight issue isn't that unusual per the number of people who have reported it.  I have tried a few things to fix it but no luck yet.

Comment: That is for sure a bug. I would contact support and have them repair/replace it under warranty. However, I'd try a reset first to make sure it's not a software problem. Make sure to back up your data! :)